# How can I stream the incoming contents of a file to a remote server?

Tags: linux

I'd like to ideally be able to do

echo "1" > file

and that file is being monitored or maybe the file itself is an app that just forwards all contents that's about to be written to another server or source.

Any idea how I can do this or where I should start looking?  I tried a few searches online but came up short

Answer (score 1):

Use a network file system like [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) or [smbfs](https://www.samba.org/) or any other network enabled FS. You may consider using [FUSE](http://www.linux.org/threads/fuse.6211/) (Filesystem in USErspace) if you don't want to use root account to be able to perform mounts. FUSE also has a bunch of "modules" providing access for different "file-like" network protocols, like [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS), [ftpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPFS), [webdav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davfs2) etc